# Is TeXLive 2010 faster than MiKTeX 2.9?

Tags: texlive, miktex

Some guys say that TeXLive 2010 compiles faster than MikTeX 2.9, while others say that this is not true and say that the speed of the two systems is similar.
What do you think? Please explain your reasons to support your viewpoints.

Comment: This site is only for Q&A, not for discussions. You could post it in [comp.text.tex](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.text.tex/topics) instead.

Comment: @Martin Scharrer: Ok. So my question is: Is TeXLive 2010 faster than MiKTeX 2.9?

Comment: IMHO it is still 'argumentative', which disqualifies it. Simply install both on the same machine and measure the time!

Comment: Is TeXlive 2011 available or is that a typo?

Comment: @frabjous: http://www.tug.org/texlive/: "Current release: 2010"

Comment: “What do you think? [...] explain your reasons to support your viewpoints.” really reminds me of essay assignments in school.

Comment: @Caramdir: yes, You'r right. This part of my question is so formal.

Comment: @Martin, thanks. @Vahid If you do decide to test, be sure to disable MikTeX's "install missing packages on the fly" feature, since that could significantly slow down compilation, but unfairly so, since the packages need to be installed at *some* point.

Comment: Why is this question important? On modern machines, both are sufficiently fast to make any difference insignificant.

Comment: It could depend on format files, using fonts, different engines, so I doubt such a general question would be much useful. The high number of comments without any answer until now is a sign that the question is controversial. Note that it might be closed. Btw. such an open question could be made community wiki, because you don't expect one best answer but many contributions.

Comment: @Yossi: Sometimes the run times on my modern laptop last for 40-50 seconds. So I think it is important to choose the faster system.

Comment: If I weren't a moderator, I would vote-to-close this.  It is either "subjective and argumentative" or "too localised" depending on how the question is interpreted.  For the "too localised", I don't think that this _type_ of question is all that helpful and illuminating to others since an answer would (as Herbert says) depend on too many factors.  You could ask a more focussed question on how to speed up compilation time (though I think that questions along those lines have been asked before so read those first, please).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A lot of time is used by searching and loading all the files and there are a lot to load. The basic TeX engine is the same, so it depends on the configuration of your local system. You can only compare run times on the same machine with both installed, MiKTeX and TeXLive. Comparing run times when an example runs on different machines makes no sense, too many dependencies to the system configuration.

However, on the same machine you can also have some differences depending on the file seaching and loading. And it maybe that sometimes MiKTeX is faster and sometimes TeXLive ...